# Excel Help - using IF and WORKDAY functions to generate a due date

Tags: excel

I am trying to forumlate an IF statement that will generate a due date by taking a given date and adding business days to that dependent on a value in a separate column.

I started off with:

```
=IF(E3="Fatal",D3+1,IF(E3="Life Threatening",D3+1,IF(E3="Non-Fatal",D3+3,IF(E2="Non-Life Threatening",D3+3,IF(E3="Non-Susar",D3+5,"")))))
```

But this does not use the WORKDAY or WORKDAY.INT functions at all and is something I am now needing to add. I have collated a list of bank holidays to add into the new function these are listed - `'Backend Sheet (No Edit)'!C1:C752`

Example of the sheet is below, I basically need to have it add 1,3,5 business days to the "query received date" dependent on the value in the "seriousness" column and print the new date into the "first attempt due by date" column

[image: Screen Grab]

Appreciate any help that can be given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your seriousness in a separate helper table along with the days adjustment. Then use `workday` to find your attempt date.

`=workday([date received], index([helper table adjustment],match([this table seriousness],[helper table seriousness],0)),'Backend Sheet (No Edit)'!C1:C752)`

Comment: Okay, I've tried using 'NETWORKINGDAYS' but I'm failing miserably. 

https://imgur.com/a/4NsKG

In the above example sheet I am using:

'=NETWORKDAYS(A2, INDEX(F3:F7,MATCH(B2,E3:E7,0)),I3:I754)'

but its returning XXXXX

Comment: Sorry, end_date needs to be [*date received + *index...]. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Ah the workday edit worked! Thanks massively a-burge, you may just have saved  some lives.

Comment: Sincerely hope that excel is not used to save lives (although so far it has had its role in ruining some). But happy to help.